# How to use like and between together in sql?

Tags: php, mysql, database, web

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM justshawarma_nexo_commandes where REF_CLIENT = '$uuc' 
and DATE_CREATION like '%$date3%' and DATE_CREATION like '%$date4%'";
```

This is my query.I want to fetch the records that match between two dates. But my date column in the table contains both date and time.That is why i want to use like and between.

What is the error in this code?

Comment: Use between? ...Where DATE_CREATION  between '$date3' AND '$date4'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   $between['date_from'] =  date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date3))." 00:00:00";
    $between['date_to'] = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($date4))." 23:59:59";


 $query = "SELECT * FROM justshawarma_nexo_commandes where REF_CLIENT = '$uuc' and DATE_CREATION BETWEEN '".$between['date_from']."' AND '".$between['date_to']."';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use BETWEEN condition:

```php
$query = "SELECT * FROM justshawarma_nexo_commandes where REF_CLIENT = '$uuc' and DATE_CREATION BETWEEN '$date3' and '$date4'";
```

Comment: my date column in table contains both date and time.

Answer (score 0):

With Like Your Query Will Look Like Something Below

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM justshawarma_nexo_commandes 
          where REF_CLIENT = \'$uuc\' 
          and DATE_CREATION like %\'$date3\'% 
          and DATE_CREATION like %\'$date4\'%";
```

With Between

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM justshawarma_nexo_commandes 
          where REF_CLIENT = \'$uuc\' 
          and DATE_CREATION Between \'$date3 00:00:00\' 
          and \'$date4 23:59:59\'";
```

As You said you have time in your column so you can select all the records between that date range using these queries.

Comment: when you copy&pasted those queries some escaping `\` where added. I'm sure you didn't mean it that way..

Answer (score 0):

> Try this. this will work fine for me, Here my some part of my Order_ID having Date:

```
  SELECT *
          FROM [MABH-Desi-Dera].[dbo].[Order] where(CONVERT(nvarchar,[Order_ID]) BETWEEN  '200622%' AND '200623%' )
```

Answer (score 0):

Include `DATE()` in your SQL statement since you said you column includes datetime Like …

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM justshawarma_nexo_commandes where REF_CLIENT = '$uuc' 
    and DATE(DATE_CREATION) BETWEEN '$date3' and '$date4'";
```